How to fit different size images to "box" in Woocommerce catalog
the catalogue now
because of the size of picture is different, so the image in catalogue is different size.
I hope the catalogue page can be like this,
in same size "box"
the size in catalogue can be the same size.

Go to Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images, choose 1:1 in cropping settings and change the Thumbnail width size.
Make sure to manually regenerate the thumbnails from WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Regenerate Thumbnails afterwards.
